# In Geben, how can you jump to the currently paused line from any buffer

Tags: php-mode

When debugging PHP with Geben and xdebug, how do you jump to the currently paused line (The line with a => mark in the margin) from any buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>w</kbd> calls `geben-where`:

```
geben-where is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `geben.el'.

(geben-where)

Move to the current breaking point.
```

It is also bound to <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-l</kbd> which, from the comments, may be consistent with `gud` behaviour and bindings.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there are any tutorials on Geben anywhere, it's a big package and I'm having trouble figuring out several issues

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.  This site is a good place to ask those questions, though.

Comment: https://github.com/ahungry/geben has useful information of course, if by some chance you hadn't already seen that.

Comment: Yeah, I did, but its a little bit thin. I think I will probably be posting more questions :)